# Timer for a dictionary

Tags: c#, timer

I have created dynamic timer.  The time has to take time intervals from the dictionary. But when I run the program it says that my  index is not exist. and it just says it when I but y=0;

```
var timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

int track = 0;
int y = 0; 
timer.Tick += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
{
    timer.Interval = pQueuValues[y];
    if (track < nodenum)
    {
          txtOutput.Text += "\r\r\n" + "The Node name is:  " + normalQueuName[track] + "  With the priority:  " + pQueuValues[track];
           ++track;
     }  
     else
     {
           timer.Stop();
     }
  };

 timer.Start();
```

Comment: What basic debugging have you done?

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: NO this a part from big program. The only thing that it reject to accept the value 0

Comment: pQueuValues is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `int` as the key type, the dictionary indexes by key not the numerical position of the element.  So if you don't have an element with a key with a value of 0, it will fail.  You can use the `ElementAt` method which will use the position index:

```
timer.Interval = pQueuValues.ElementAt(y).Value;
```